# Map values in each object to be new series of key value pairs (Moongoose validation error to Vee Validate field validation message)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validation, mongoose, vee-validate

I am trying to turn the error messages of Validation from Mongoose into readable data for Vee Validate.

In this case I am using [mongoose unique validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-unique-validator) to enforce unique emails. I get the errors of this in this email example and get the following:

```
{
 email: {
  kind: "unique",
  path: "email",
  message: "Email address seems to already exist",
  path: "email",
  type: "unique",
  value: "email@email.com",
 }
}
```

I return this as the json error data where I add it to [Vee Validate using `setErrors`](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/advanced/server-side-validation.html#setting-errors-manually)

So in this case I want the object to turn into:

```
{
  email: ['Email address seems to already exist']
}
```

So I want to map one object to another while still allowing more than one erroring field to be exist in case more server side validation existed that frontend couldn't cover.

I am open to solutions that are changing the validation error object itself but I haven't found anything useful with moongoose validation yet.

Comment: Let me understand this. You wan to convert
`{email: {message: "email error"}, password: {message: "password error"}}` to `{email: ["email error"], password: ["password error"]}`

Comment: @HaseebA that's correct, with your added example of if a password error existed as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to convert `{email: {message: "email error"}, password: {message: "password error"}}` to `{email: ["email error"], password: ["password error"]}`

You can use reduce function (with Object.keys to convert to array):

```js
const data = {
  email: {
    message: "Inavlid email"
  },
  username: {
    message: "Inavlid username"
  },
  password: {
    message: "Inavlid password"
  }
};

const transformed = Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, k) => {
  return {
    [k]: [data[k].message],
    ...acc
  };
}, {});

console.log(transformed)
// transformed = {email: ["Invalid email"], username: ["Invalid username"], password: ["Invalid password"]};
```